# Webservice taking long time to response

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a client server application. My server is in PHP, Mysql and Apache and client is developed using C# windows Form. I have SOAP WSDL webservice for client server communication.
Recently I found a problem, when my client sends the request, response comes after very long time (like 3/4 mins to some hrs.), and sometimes I never gets response. I have checked all the timeout value in client (httpwebrequest timeout, readwritetimeout) as well as server(timeout, keepalivetimeout) side, the max value I have is 5mins (for httpwebrequest readwritetimeout). So can anybody tell what would be the problem? Why it is taking hours to get response or not geting any response?

Comment: I have a feeling your server is overloaded. Extremely long response times are strange, but I would say that your request is idle until the server can process it.

Comment: so what kind of settings i will have to do either on server or client side. What i want is if it taking such a long time then the request should get timeout so, I can send fresh request and the first request should get cancelled.

Comment: I am not sure what you can do here because I have not worked with SOAP. However, I would like to point out that if you have such crazy long wait times for responses, trying to brute force a response by re-initializing is not a very sustainable solution and can only stress the server even more (going along with my assumption that the server is overloaded). If the responses were 5 seconds then its ok, but a few minutes to a few hours is a red flag that the server your sending the request to needs attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, problems like these come with the web-service connection being blocked by a firewall, or a wonky proxy in the way. Check that this is not the issue.

You should first begin be locating the problem by narrowing down the options. Have you tried calling the web service on the server locally, see if you get the same problem - if you don't then it is with high likeliness certainly a connection problem.

To also rule out the client having problems, try using something like http://www.soapui.org/ instead to call your server web service.

Where are you calling the server from? Are you sure the device you call it from is not being IP-blocked, and are you sure your web service is able to access its database from where it is being run.

Does the MySQL user defined for your server API to use have access from the IP of the server. MySQL users are often blocked by IP as well.

If you're running it all locally, are you sure your IIS Express settings/virtual folders are not jumbled up and the URLs are resolving wrong. Try creating the virtual folder again to rule out this. Even when running locally, remember to check that the MySQL user has access from your local IP.

Here's a few things I usually check when I have issues like yours.

Comment: The server I am using is my production server and I am using apache. My mysql IP is 'localhost' for my php code. As far as checking locally, I have never found it on my development machine but, still I will keep it today for overnight testing on local server. Also, I don't get this problem everytime but sometimes after 3/4 hrs.